# Application Connect Excel sheet to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I  am stuck at below mentioned situation guide me. I have one user form i made in excel . i can try to perform crud i have completed insert.  i can try to update or delete not working please give me some idea.
this is my insert code it is properly working

```vb
insert:-
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim cn As Object
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim City As String
    Dim myDB As String
    Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Initialize Variables
    Name = Me.TextBox1.Value
    City = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Dept = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    myDB = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\nis\ni2\em.accdb"
   'Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"    'For *.ACCDB Databases
        .ConnectionString = myDB
        .Open
        MsgBox "con created"
    End With
     strQuery = "INSERT INTO emp ([Name], [City],[Dept]) " & _
               "VALUES (""" & Name & """, """ & City & """,""" & Dept & """); "
MsgBox "success fully insert"
    cn.Execute strQuery
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
update code:-
Dim cn As Object
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim City As String
    Dim myDB As String
    Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Initialize Variables
'    Name = Me.TextBox1.Value
'    City = Me.TextBox2.Value
'    Dept = Me.ComboBox1.Value
     myDB = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\nis\ni2\em.accdb"
   'Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"    'For *.ACCDB Databases
        .ConnectionString = myDB
        .Open
        MsgBox "con created"
    End With
     strQuery = "Update emp Set  [Name]='" & Me.TextBox1.Value & "',"&[City]='" & TextBox2.Value & "',&[Dept]='" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & "'"
MsgBox "success fully insert"
    cn.Execute strQuery
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
  strQuery = "Update emp Set  [Name]='" & Me.TextBox1.Value & "',"&[City]='" & TextBox2.Value & "',&[Dept]='" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & "'"
```

is attempting to update all lines in the emp table with those values. I suspect you only want to update one line. You need to add a WHERE clause to specify which line.

EDIT: Just noticed there's a syntax error in that line as well. It should read

```
 strQuery = "Update emp Set [Name]='" & Me.TextBox1.Value & "', [City]='" & TextBox2.Value & "',[Dept]='" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & "' Where "
```

and then should finish with your where clause